# Insights API returning data empty array

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Im trying to retrieve lead ads data specifically the current spent.

for the finished lead ads i can retrieved it with no problems.

but for the currently running leads are most of it can't pull any data  and one of it can but i retrieved a value inaccurately so bad. I only received 1.77 but the current spendings is 50+

ENDPOINT: /{ad-id}/insights

sample return:

```
array:1 [
"data" => []
]
```

data that i can retrieved. same value with finished lead ads:

```
array:2 [
"data" => array:1 [
      0 => array:8 [
          "account_id" => "#####"
          "ad_id" => "#####"
          "campaign_id" => "#####"
          "adset_id" => "#####"
          "date_start" => "2023-11-12"
          "date_stop" => "2023-12-11"
          "impressions" => ""
          "spend" => "1.77"
      ]
]
"paging" => array:1 [
     "cursors" => array:2 [
         "before" => ""
         "after" => ""
      ]
  ]
]
```

tried this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights

expected to receive a values all the time not empty array